# VSCode feature that can provide options for poorly written code like PyCharm

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find the settings that enable checking code a lot like the features in PyCharm.

Ex. Let's say you're using the request library to perform an API call. The API call returns a JSON file that is for the most part empty.

```
[
{"companies":[]}
]
```

And I'm tired, not thinking...whatever. And I write something like this:

```
r = request...
data = r.json()
if data['companies'] == []:
    return 'It's empty'
```

That's poorly written. PyCharm would place the wiggle lines under it. And you can right-click and have PyCharm fix it and make it correct.

```
r = request...
data = r.json()
if not data['companies']:
    return 'It's empty'
```

Of course, this was a no-brainer. I just wanted to give a simple example. However, at times this may happen. I can't find where in VSCode to enable this.

Thank you!

Comment: that is called Linting, search the VSC docs of supported linters and set it up for the one you like

Comment: @rioV8 Concerning your comment "that is called Linting, search the VSC docs of supported linters and set it up for the one you like –" THANK YOU! I didn't know that. I didn't know anything about "linting". Now, I can go and research "linting". But, without the foundation (linting) I didn't know where to begin researching.  I asked the same question twice because SOF took down my 1st ques. saying that I was asking for recommendations on software that is not allowed. I was trying to gain usage out of the software I was using. And there are other questions on SOF that do ask for recommendations